# Append duplicate column into one column in python

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to append but I have no solution for this. Could you help me?

Input:

```
no   abc   abc  abc
1    a1    b1   c1
2    a1    b2   c2
3    a2    b2   c3
```

Output:

```
no   abc   
1    a1    
2    a1    
3    a2    
4    b1
5    b2
6    b2
7    c1
8    c2
9    c3
```

p/s: I already fixed my first post !

Comment: Are you talking about lists? numpy arrays? pandas DataFrame? please be more specific and add some data samples for us to use.

Comment: please provide more data

Comment: Sorry I'm a newcomer here ! I already fixed my post !

Comment: @Crist2002 can you confirm you are use pandas?

Comment: Yeah ! I confirm

Comment: Then check my answer below ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a pandas dataframe from the formatting, `pandas.melt` should to the trick:

```
(df.melt(id_vars='no', value_name='abc')
   .drop(columns='variable')
)
```

output:

```
   no abc
0   1  a1
1   2  a1
2   3  a2
3   1  b1
4   2  b2
5   3  b2
6   1  c1
7   2  c2
8   3  c3
```